# Spring project error using thymeleaf, Compilation failure. How can I fix this?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm pretty new at Spring framework, and I try to start a project for practice. 
But I have an error and I have no idea how to fix this.

I've created a new Spring project in IntelliJ Idea, with Spring Initializr option (In Intellij, not with start.spring.io ). I added only 2 dependedncies for start (Web and Thymeleaf), but it throws error for Thymeleaf dependency if i run it with 
'mvn spring-boot:run' command.

My spring project is "empty" , I have no controllers, beans, jpa entites, etc.. but it i think it shound run in this way too. I just wanted to make sure if it works if I run it.

If I create a same project, without Thymeleaf dependency (only Web dependency), it starts correctly on localhost.

I'm using Java 9.0.4 and Apache Maven 3.5.3

[My error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inygG.jpg)

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo_thymeleaf</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo_thymeleaf</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>9</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with deleting the whole C\Users\user.m2 directory.

After then with 'mvn spring-boot:run' it started successfully on localhost.

But I've got one more question: 
When I run it, at terminal there are a couple of Warning messages.

Spring application runs anyway, but is there something to do with these messages?

[Warning messages during Spring application run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UG8D.jpg)